# Is it possible to move questions between Stack Overflow and ServerFault?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, migration, serverfault

I've accidentally asked sysadmin questions on Stack Overflow and programming questions on ServerFault. Is it possible to move them from one to the other?

Suggestion: I wish I could make them look totally different (by selecting a skin with contrastingly different colors)

Comment: I would recommend breaking this into separate questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Just flag the posts and request that they be migrated.

Comment: i tried to do that, but serverfault did not appear on the list of sites which i could ask to migrate the question to...

Answer (score 2):

There are already some user styles for SO. E.g. this one: https://userstyles.org/styles/12768

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution is for people to close such questions as "Belongs on ServerFault."  If you have fewer than 250 reputation, make a comment and flag the question for moderation attention.

Also, you can change the appearance of the sites by using a [user stylesheet](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/ht/htcssuserfirefo.htm).  The mechanism varies by browser.