# Are any answered questions on Meta valid if Jeff, Joel, Moderator X don't answer them?

Tags: discussion, answers, meta

Are any answered questions on Meta valid if Jeff, Joel, Moderator X don't answer them?

For example: [Gaming the system with spam flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49159/gaming-the-system-with-spam-flags)

plus 100s of others

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course. Plenty of questions are factual: "How do I do such and such?" (e.g. 
[Is it possible to move questions between stackoverflow and serverfault?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49065/is-it-possible-to-move-questions-between-stackoverflow-and-serverfault/49068#49068)).  There's no need for mods to spend time on these.

Answer (score 7):

Definitely.

It's all about delegation.

The Meta community at large has enough knowledge to solve 90% of the issues that end up here, so there's no need for the small number of moderators to give answers to all the questions. (Notable exceptions include bugs that are *actually* bugs, and feature requests that ultimately get implemented by the development team.)

A moderator's function on the site(s) is to facilitate the discussions, not necessarily to always be involved in them (although that is their own personal choice).

(I should point out that if a mod chooses to not answer *this* question, I think that gives you a pretty good answer in itself.)

Comment: At your last paragraph: Yea, a good answer unless it's an actual bug that for whatever reason no moderator would respond to

Answer (score 3):

They can be valid. I always vote up things that are correct here. In general if you see an answer with a lot of votes that isn't on a [discussion] question, that is because it is a valid, correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

[Gaming the system with spam flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49159/gaming-the-system-with-spam-flags) is a `[discussion]` question.  "The Team" is not required to participate in such questions.  However, I am quite sure *they do read them,* as they are tantamount to free market research.

If you want "The Team" to participate in your questions, flag them with `[bug]` or `[feature-request]` (if appropriate).

Comment: or maybe **`[support]`** I think the team looks at those closer than **`[discussion]`**